Conditionally changing Chart bar color in JasperSoft Studio 6.19.0
I'm using Jaspersoft Community Edition. Could you help me keep the bar of chart always green if classificacao field is "A", yellow if it is "B" and red if it is "C". The Source of my report is this:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Created with Jaspersoft Studio version 6.19.0.final using JasperReports Library version 6.19.0-646c68931cebf1a58bc65c4359d1f0ca223c5e94  -->
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="isp_crp" pageWidth="842" pageHeight="595" orientation="Landscape" columnWidth="802" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="528085cb-e8a5-4d21-b78d-8b83b53a8227">
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.sql.tables" value=""/>
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.defaultdataadapter" value="gabamfs_Adapter"/>
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.sql.SQLQueryDesigner.sash.w1" value="148"/>
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.sql.SQLQueryDesigner.sash.w2" value="841"/>
    <parameter name="dt_exercicio" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
    <parameter name="no_ente" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <queryString language="SQL">
        <![CDATA[select 
dt_exercicio,
id.no_ente,
initcap(grupo) as grupo,
initcap(subgrupo) as subgrupo, 
classificacao,
saldo_dair_exerc_anterior,
  saldo_dair_exerc_atual,
 replace(replace(replace(acrescimo_decrescimo_no_saldo_dos_ativos_financeiros,'.',''),',','.'),'-','0')::numeric
  as acrescimo_decrescimo_no_saldo_dos_ativos_financeiros, 
  acrescimo_decrescimo_no_saldo_dos_ativos_financeiros,
  total_das_despesas_previdenciarias_rreo_6_bim,
  despesas_previdenciarias_apos_deducoes_rreo_6_bim,
  replace(replace(pontuacao,',','.'),'-','0')::numeric as pontuacao,
  replace(replace(pri_tercil,',','.'),'-','0')::numeric as pri_tercil,
  replace(replace(seg_tercil,',','.'),'-','0')::numeric as seg_tercil
from isp_acumulacao ia
left join
isp_de_para id
on id.no_ente_isp=ia.no_ente
where ia.sg_uf='SP' 
     AND ia.dt_exercicio BETWEEN $P{dt_exercicio}-3 AND $P{dt_exercicio} 
     AND id.no_ente =  $P{no_ente} 
ORDER BY ia.dt_exercicio]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="dt_exercicio" class="java.math.BigDecimal">
        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.field.name" value="dt_exercicio"/>
        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.field.label" value="dt_exercicio"/>
        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.field.tree.path" value="isp_acumulacao"/>
    </field>
    <field name="no_ente" class="java.lang.String">
        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.field.name" value="no_ente"/>
        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.field.label" value="no_ente"/>
        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.field.tree.path" value="isp_de_para"/>
    </field>
    <field name="grupo" class="java.lang.String">
        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.field.name" value="grupo"/>
        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.field.label" value="grupo"/>
    </field>
    <field name="subgrupo" class="java.lang.String">
        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.field.name" value="subgrupo"/>
        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.field.label" value="subgrupo"/>
    </field>
    <field name="classificacao" class="java.lang.String">
        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.field.name" value="classificacao"/>
        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.field.label" value="classificacao"/>
        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.field.tree.path" value="isp_acumulacao"/>
    </field>
    <field name="saldo_dair_exerc_anterior" class="java.lang.String">
        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.field.name" value="saldo_dair_exerc_anterior"/>
        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.field.label" value="saldo_dair_exerc_anterior"/>
        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.field.tree.path" value="isp_acumulacao"/>
    </field>
    <field name="saldo_dair_exerc_atual" class="java.lang.String">
        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.field.name" value="saldo_dair_exerc_atual"/>
        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.field.label" value="saldo_dair_exerc_atual"/>
        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.field.tree.path" value="isp_acumulacao"/>
    </field>
    <field name="acrescimo_decrescimo_no_saldo_dos_ativos_financeiros" class="java.math.BigDecimal">
        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.field.name" value="acrescimo_decrescimo_no_saldo_dos_ativos_financeiros"/>
        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.field.label" value="acrescimo_decrescimo_no_saldo_dos_ativos_financeiros"/>
        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.field.tree.path" value="isp_acumulacao"/>
    </field>
    <field name="COLUMN_9" class="java.lang.String">
        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.field.name" value="acrescimo_decrescimo_no_saldo_dos_ativos_financeiros"/>
        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.field.label" value="acrescimo_decrescimo_no_saldo_dos_ativos_financeiros"/>
        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.field.tree.path" value="isp_acumulacao"/>
    </field>
    <field name="total_das_despesas_previdenciarias_rreo_6_bim" class="java.lang.String">
        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.field.name" value="total_das_despesas_previdenciarias_rreo_6_bim"/>
        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.field.label" value="total_das_despesas_previdenciarias_rreo_6_bim"/>
        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.field.tree.path" value="isp_acumulacao"/>
    </field>
    <field name="despesas_previdenciarias_apos_deducoes_rreo_6_bim" class="java.lang.String">
        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.field.name" value="despesas_previdenciarias_apos_deducoes_rreo_6_bim"/>
        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.field.label" value="despesas_previdenciarias_apos_deducoes_rreo_6_bim"/>
        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.field.tree.path" value="isp_acumulacao"/>
    </field>
    <field name="pontuacao" class="java.math.BigDecimal">
        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.field.name" value="pontuacao"/>
        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.field.label" value="pontuacao"/>
        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.field.tree.path" value="isp_acumulacao"/>
    </field>
    <field name="pri_tercil" class="java.math.BigDecimal">
        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.field.name" value="pri_tercil"/>
        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.field.label" value="pri_tercil"/>
        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.field.tree.path" value="isp_acumulacao"/>
    </field>
    <field name="seg_tercil" class="java.math.BigDecimal">
        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.field.name" value="seg_tercil"/>
        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.field.label" value="seg_tercil"/>
        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.field.tree.path" value="isp_acumulacao"/>
    </field>
    <background>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </background>
    <title>
        <band height="81" splitType="Stretch">
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="0" y="42" width="800" height="13" forecolor="#1A0DA6" uuid="b03838e7-32db-4722-8f0f-f91aca0787eb">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.y" value="px"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="px"/>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center">
                    <font fontName="Arial" size="11" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Índice de Situação Previdenciária ISP - Indicador de Acumulação]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="0" y="67" width="800" height="10" forecolor="#0A0101" uuid="2e4b2540-9d05-415e-bf0d-fd9d68fbfa41">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="px"/>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement textAlignment="Left">
                    <font fontName="Arial" size="8" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Fonte: https://www.gov.br/previdencia/pt-br/assuntos/rpps/indice-de-situacao-previdenciaria/indice-de-situacao-previdenciaria-divulgacao-de-resultados]]></text>
            </staticText>
        </band>
    </title>
    <pageHeader>
        <band height="30" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </pageHeader>
    <columnHeader>
        <band height="42" splitType="Stretch">
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="162" y="0" width="59" height="40" uuid="98ae5ae9-7ac1-4ecc-9179-203c23c41cae">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.spreadsheet.connectionID" value="f7496642-119a-40a1-b59b-fe680486d71e"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="px"/>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="Arial" size="10"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Classificação]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="221" y="0" width="80" height="40" forecolor="#1A0DA6" uuid="290a52a6-37d0-44b0-9656-fa63e3c0cde8">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.spreadsheet.connectionID" value="25a36a4e-b70a-445d-8a26-24a33efca2f3"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="px"/>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="Arial" size="10"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Saldo Dair Exercício Anterior]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="301" y="0" width="79" height="40" uuid="21c6848f-fa9e-45f0-a486-12a0191629fc">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.spreadsheet.connectionID" value="cee39720-cff0-416c-89de-cca608f2e8f5"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="px"/>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="Arial" size="10"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Saldo Dair Exercício Atual]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="380" y="0" width="91" height="40" forecolor="#1A0DA6" uuid="05edffdf-84b0-4c5f-aecc-53e800398126">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.spreadsheet.connectionID" value="9d841be1-99fc-4503-bee5-982e6ce7240e"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="px"/>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="Arial" size="10"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Acrescimo ou Decrescimo no Dair]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="669" y="0" width="50" height="40" uuid="47af1767-d893-4d81-a3f0-c270a1ce1156">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.spreadsheet.connectionID" value="6f0c0382-fba7-462c-b041-f5af47e3d9c0"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="px"/>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="Arial" size="10"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Pontuação]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="720" y="0" width="40" height="40" forecolor="#1A0DA6" uuid="a70b7864-eb8a-4218-ac9f-760aeba4dd33">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.spreadsheet.connectionID" value="4ec8e444-d668-49c4-bd8f-70e01c0e2875"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="px"/>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="Arial" size="10"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[1º Tercil]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="760" y="0" width="40" height="40" uuid="98cff5c7-1cd2-4c1d-b469-b1a21da75a76">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.spreadsheet.connectionID" value="faf781a1-f619-43e6-80f5-544e6049412a"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="px"/>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="Arial" size="10"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[2º Tercil]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="51" y="0" width="50" height="40" uuid="950854ff-471d-4544-907e-3f8796ab2ba8">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.spreadsheet.connectionID" value="f7496642-119a-40a1-b59b-fe680486d71e"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="px"/>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="Arial" size="10"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Grupo]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="101" y="0" width="60" height="40" forecolor="#1A0DA6" uuid="ee41e4c1-ede6-44b7-8385-812b137e319f">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.spreadsheet.connectionID" value="f7496642-119a-40a1-b59b-fe680486d71e"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="px"/>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="Arial" size="10"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Subgrupo]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="50" height="40" forecolor="#1A0DA6" uuid="7c113c5c-6c61-480c-b1f8-18bc874883ca">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.spreadsheet.connectionID" value="f7496642-119a-40a1-b59b-fe680486d71e"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="px"/>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="Arial" size="10"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Exercício]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="471" y="0" width="100" height="40" uuid="3f842cc9-e490-458b-9ac1-854ffb24dc41">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.spreadsheet.connectionID" value="cee39720-cff0-416c-89de-cca608f2e8f5"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="px"/>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="Arial" size="10"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Total Despesas Previdenciárias RREO 6º Bimestre]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="571" y="0" width="98" height="40" forecolor="#1A0DA6" uuid="71ee4a7a-a25e-49b1-9c70-c50290180c55">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.spreadsheet.connectionID" value="9d841be1-99fc-4503-bee5-982e6ce7240e"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="px"/>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="Arial" size="10"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Despesas Previdenciárias Apos Deduções]]></text>
            </staticText>
        </band>
    </columnHeader>
    <detail>
        <band height="33" splitType="Stretch">
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="0" y="3" width="50" height="30" forecolor="#1A0DA6" uuid="722b4ff2-6baa-48cf-8873-6209432c3187">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.spreadsheet.connectionID" value="cdab2132-1a2d-455a-bca2-e5e05b610fb5"/>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="Arial" size="10"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{dt_exercicio}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="162" y="3" width="59" height="30" uuid="84034d72-5d77-4e3b-b459-a667593bf670">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.spreadsheet.connectionID" value="f7496642-119a-40a1-b59b-fe680486d71e"/>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="Arial" size="10"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{classificacao}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="221" y="3" width="80" height="30" forecolor="#1A0DA6" uuid="1633e465-bd44-458e-bd40-c7a048dc0133">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.spreadsheet.connectionID" value="25a36a4e-b70a-445d-8a26-24a33efca2f3"/>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="Arial" size="10"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{saldo_dair_exerc_anterior}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="301" y="3" width="79" height="30" uuid="3c0fa84b-bea5-4fb5-8045-a85a5004cea4">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.spreadsheet.connectionID" value="cee39720-cff0-416c-89de-cca608f2e8f5"/>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="Arial" size="10"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{saldo_dair_exerc_atual}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="380" y="3" width="91" height="30" forecolor="#1A0DA6" uuid="bef3dd19-8b00-4b90-af40-0708e8b8cd2a">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.spreadsheet.connectionID" value="9d841be1-99fc-4503-bee5-982e6ce7240e"/>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="Arial" size="10"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{acrescimo_decrescimo_no_saldo_dos_ativos_financeiros}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="669" y="3" width="50" height="30" uuid="5ce74f52-4686-4dbd-8f0c-ee31de4e268a">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.spreadsheet.connectionID" value="6f0c0382-fba7-462c-b041-f5af47e3d9c0"/>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="Arial" size="10"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{pontuacao}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="720" y="3" width="40" height="30" forecolor="#1A0DA6" uuid="fc029335-594b-4a82-8215-63380fcc65e0">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.spreadsheet.connectionID" value="4ec8e444-d668-49c4-bd8f-70e01c0e2875"/>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="Arial" size="10"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{pri_tercil}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="760" y="3" width="40" height="30" uuid="4803bf5b-0709-464a-a5f4-4cb1eb862309">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.spreadsheet.connectionID" value="faf781a1-f619-43e6-80f5-544e6049412a"/>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="Arial" size="10"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{seg_tercil}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <line>
                <reportElement x="0" y="1" width="800" height="1" forecolor="#960F21" uuid="1f917a94-3e2a-4af0-ab12-b2ce0acb09ed"/>
            </line>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="51" y="3" width="50" height="30" uuid="99699e90-c2c4-4577-b2f1-8dd5ce1aec2f">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.spreadsheet.connectionID" value="8702667c-972e-43c8-9e84-026ce77b6efd"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="px"/>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="Arial" size="10"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{grupo}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="101" y="3" width="60" height="30" forecolor="#1A0DA6" uuid="4be3068c-98fd-4298-a341-5f0015eacc36">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.spreadsheet.connectionID" value="ed566ba6-52bd-43a7-94a6-cd560fdc0849"/>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="Arial" size="10"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{subgrupo}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="471" y="3" width="100" height="30" uuid="a3b513cf-9912-4e2b-8aec-6d82aa8acbb0">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.spreadsheet.connectionID" value="cee39720-cff0-416c-89de-cca608f2e8f5"/>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="Arial" size="10"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{total_das_despesas_previdenciarias_rreo_6_bim}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="571" y="3" width="98" height="30" forecolor="#1A0DA6" uuid="62f6fc77-386c-4389-b6bf-480e05230f15">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.spreadsheet.connectionID" value="9d841be1-99fc-4503-bee5-982e6ce7240e"/>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="Arial" size="10"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{despesas_previdenciarias_apos_deducoes_rreo_6_bim}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </detail>
    <columnFooter>
        <band height="20" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </columnFooter>
    <pageFooter>
        <band height="21" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </pageFooter>
    <summary>
        <band height="220" splitType="Stretch">
            <barChart>
                <chart evaluationTime="Report">
                    <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="710" height="160" uuid="971f988c-e050-4b5b-bc95-defbcb6483ab"/>
                    <chartTitle/>
                    <chartSubtitle/>
                    <chartLegend/>
                </chart>
                <categoryDataset>
                    <dataset resetType="Report"/>
                    <categorySeries>
                        <seriesExpression><![CDATA[$F{classificacao}]]></seriesExpression>
                        <categoryExpression><![CDATA[$F{dt_exercicio}]]></categoryExpression>
                        <valueExpression><![CDATA[$F{pontuacao}]]></valueExpression>
                        <labelExpression><![CDATA[$F{classificacao}]]></labelExpression>
                    </categorySeries>
                </categoryDataset>
                <barPlot isShowLabels="true" isShowTickLabels="true" isShowTickMarks="true">
                    <plot>
                        <seriesColor seriesOrder="0" color="#BD6FB8"/>
                        <seriesColor seriesOrder="1" color="#0909E3"/>
                    </plot>
                    <itemLabel/>
                    <categoryAxisFormat>
                        <axisFormat labelColor="#000000" tickLabelColor="#000000" axisLineColor="#000000"/>
                    </categoryAxisFormat>
                    <valueAxisFormat>
                        <axisFormat labelColor="#000000" tickLabelColor="#000000" axisLineColor="#000000"/>
                    </valueAxisFormat>
                </barPlot>
            </barChart>
        </band>
    </summary>
</jasperReport>

The chart in my screen
If you need anything more, please ask me!
I use netbeans IDE.
If necessary tell me how to use it to get what I need.
